# Java DNS revese lookup with classless delegation

Tags: java, dns

We are trying to resove this IP address 81.95.126.172, dig produces

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
172.126.95.81.in-addr.arpa. 974 IN      CNAME   172.128-26.126.95.81.in-addr.arpa.
172.128-26.126.95.81.in-addr.arpa. 32757 IN PTR hosted-by.futureweb.be.
```

But in Java, this test fails, because getHostName() returns same IP address.

```
@Test
public void aaa() throws UnknownHostException {
    assertNull(System.getSecurityManager());
    assertEquals("hosted-by.futureweb.be", InetAddress.getByName("81.95.126.172").getHostName());
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadocs for `getHostName()`:

> If there is a security manager, its checkConnect method is first called with the 
>   hostname and -1 as its arguments to see if the operation is allowed. If the
>   operation is not allowed, it will return the textual representation of the IP address.
>
> **Returns:**
>   the host name for this IP address, or if the operation is not allowed by the security check, the
>   textual representation of the IP address.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no security manager, checked by `assertNull(System.getSecurityManager());`